# Postback problem with partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following view

```
<form action="/Questionnaire/Submit" method="post">
  <%:"UserName : "%>

  <%=ViewData["UserName"]%>
 <%=Html.TextBox("test",ViewData["tt"])%>
<p />
 <%:"Phone Number :"%>

 <%=ViewData["PhoneNumber"]%>
 <p />
 <%
  foreach (var q in Model)
   {
       Html.RenderPartial("Question", q);

   }
 %>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

That render the following partial view

```
<%    using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Questionnaire", FormMethod.Post))
      {%>

<%:"Question Number "%>
<%=Model.QuestionNumber%>
<%:"  "%>
<%=Model.Body%>
<%:"  "%>
<%
      foreach (var option in Model.Options)
      {%>
      <p/>

   <%=Html.RadioButton(option.QuestionId.ToString(), (option.IsSelected) )%> &nbsp;<%=     option.OptionBody%>
      <%
      }
  }
%>
```

The problem is , The form dosn't submit , and when I remove the "foreach" statment from the master view, It works

My Objective, is to have the updated model ( from the master view and partial view ) to save it later on in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your master view contains a form and then your partial view also creates a form each time it renders, so you will be left with a page containing multiple forms but only one 'Submit' button.

I'm not 100% certain what you need to do, but I'd try and remove the '`BeginForm`' call from the partial and see if that fixes the problem.